# Renew Let's encrypt certificate automatically without stopping nginx hosted on docker

Tags: docker, nginx, letsencrypt

I am using nginx as proxy and SSL termination for the site hosted on docker. App & nginx both are on docker. I have installed Let's encrypt SSL using Certbot directly on Ubuntu server. And now using the SSL cert installed on Ubuntu server in Docker by mapping it using volume in docker-compose.

I noticed that Certbot cron job to renew certificate is failing as the port 80 and 443 are in use by docker nginx instance.

And to renew, I need to stop the docker and then run certbot renew command which works fine.

What is the best way to have automated renewal without stopping docker container that runs nginx.